# Automatic Date & Time update results in wrong time on Linux Machine

Tags: linux, fedora, ntpd

I am using Fedora 29, with kernel version 4.19.15-300 on my laptop.  It has been a while that I see the computer clock is about 6 to 7 minutes ahead.

Pondering why, I checked the status of `chronyd` (`systemctl status chronyd.service`) and I see the following log message repeated every time the machine is resumed from sleep:

```
chronyd[812]: Forward time jump detected!
```

Also, the output of `chronyc source` is an empty list.  Does this mean that there is a problem in the configuration of NTP on the machine, and that the time has never been actually synchronized?  Could anyone help me to fix the issue?

---

P.S.  I had (wrongly) asked this question on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616923/automatic-date-time-update-results-in-wrong-time-on-linux-machine).  I was suggested to check the status of `ntpd` and it seems it is disabled by default:

```
$ service ntpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status ntpd.service
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```